# Should I use the same variable name for my Twig template as the one I have in my controller?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm going through Symfony2 start guide and my question is:

I have a database with columns: price,description,id,name
Then in my controller I fetch these columns and display them via a twig template.
Within my controller I do:

```
public function showAction($id)
    {
        $product = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('AcmeStoreBundle:Product')
            ->find($id);

        if (!$product) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException(
                'No product found for id '.$id
            );
        }

        $price = $product -> getPrice();
        $description = $product -> getDescription();
        return $this->render(
        'AcmeStoreBundle:Store:index.html.twig',
        array('id' => $id, 'price' => $price, 'description' => $description)
        );
    }
```

My question is, can I change $price,$description to call it whatever else...? or am I forced to keep mentioning these variables like they're named within the database?

basically, can I do:

```
$foo = $product -> getPrice();
$bar = $product -> getDescription();
```

And then in my render function do:

```
   return $this->render(
        'AcmeStoreBundle:Store:index.html.twig',
        array('uniquecode' => $id, 'cost' => $foo, 'message' => $bar)
        );
```

My question is two fold : 1) can I do it 2) is it a good practice to do it?

Comment: You can do it :) The good practice is to keep your code readable and self-explanatory :) If you have a variable that keeps the price information don't call it `$quantity` ;)

Comment: Aha, so I can do it, but not a good practice..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better:

```
return $this->render('AcmeStoreBundle:Store:index.html.twig', array(
       'product' => $product
 ));
```

You access the product attributes in twig like this

```
{{ product.description }}
```

---

> Use meaningful names for variables. Variable name must define the
>   exact explanation of its content

I found it here http://codebuild.blogspot.de/2012/02/15-best-practices-of-variable-method.html but you can just google for **variable and method naming**

Comment: +1 I was just writing the very same answer ... probably wise to add that `'product' => $product` could just as well be `'another_name' => $product` but then it wouldnt make as much sense ... which is really what the original question was

Comment: Thank you. I guess I would come up with that while going through the start guide but indeed as ManseUK said .. :)

Comment: Agreed. You always want to use meaningful variable names and for that reason you would usually want to keep the variable names the same in the template as in the controller. A good way to force yourself into this habit is to use 'compact'. For example, `return compact('product');` would return an array with key product (to be used in your twig template) and value $product from your controller.